# Remove class not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

Why is the removeClass function not working in this case? Would like the button to turn back to a grey-background once it is not active.  The add class seems to work perfectly fine.

```js
  $(".tiles").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;

    $(this).addClass("active")

    $("#material" + divname).fadeIn('3000').siblings('.material').hide();

    $(this).siblings('.tiles').removeClass("active")
  });
```

```css
.material {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
  color: #13223d;
  border: 1px solid #13223d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='type' id='type3'>
  <h3>1.2.Valj Material</h3>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='marmorskivorCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='1'>marmorskivor</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='granitCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='2'>granit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='type' id='type4'>
  <h3>1.2.Valj Material</h3>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='marmorCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='3'>marmor</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='granitCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='4'>granit</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='material' id='material1'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile2.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmorskivor' value='Verde Guatemala'>
    </div>
    <p>Verde Guatemala</p>
  </a>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile1.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmorskivor' value='Bianco Carrara'>
    </div>
    <p>Bianco Carrara</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material2'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile4.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='granit' value='Nero Assolutio'>
    </div>
    <p>Nero Assolutio</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material3'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/biancocarrara.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmor' value='Bianco Carrara'>
    </div>
    <p>Bianco Carrara</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material4'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/imperialred.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='granit' value='Imperial Red'>
    </div>
    <p>Imperial Red</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vc0z16m6/1/)

Comment: Because the button (`this`) has no siblings with class `tiles`

Comment: What would be a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because siblings of the `this` buttons are not `.tiles`. The simples solution is to cache tiles collection and use it instead of traversal:

```
var $tiles = $(".tiles").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $("#material" + divname).fadeIn('3000').siblings('.material').hide();
    $tiles.not(this).removeClass("active")
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/32xwox44/1

Answer (score 2):

The buttons aren't siblings, they're cousins!

You need to go up to the parent `div`, find *it's* siblings, then their child buttons:

```js
  $(".tiles").click(function() {
    var divname = this.value;
    $(this).addClass("active")
    $("#material" + divname).fadeIn('3000').siblings('.material').hide();


    $(this).parent().siblings('.tile_btn').find('.tiles').removeClass("active")
  });
```

```css
.material {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
  color: #13223d;
  border: 1px solid #13223d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='type' id='type3'>
  <h3>1.2.Valj Material</h3>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='marmorskivorCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='1'>marmorskivor</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='granitCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='2'>granit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='type' id='type4'>
  <h3>1.2.Valj Material</h3>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='marmorCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='3'>marmor</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='granitCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='4'>granit</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='type' id='type5'>
  <h3>1.2.Valj Material</h3>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='granitCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='5'>granit</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='kalkstenCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='6'>kalksten</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='marmorCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='7'>marmor</button>
  </div>
  <div class='tile_btn'><span id='Övrigt sortimentCount'>0</span>
    <button class='tiles' type='button' name='material' value='8'>Övrigt sortiment</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='material' id='material1'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile2.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmorskivor' value='Verde Guatemala'>
    </div>
    <p>Verde Guatemala</p>
  </a>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile1.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmorskivor' value='Bianco Carrara'>
    </div>
    <p>Bianco Carrara</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material2'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile4.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='granit' value='Nero Assolutio'>
    </div>
    <p>Nero Assolutio</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material10'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/GroheEssence.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='Köksblandare' value='Grohe Essence'>
    </div>
    <p>Grohe Essence</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material9'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/BlancoSubline700-U.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='Diskhoar' value='Blanco Subline 700-U'>
    </div>
    <p>Blanco Subline 700-U</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material3'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/biancocarrara.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmor' value='Bianco Carrara'>
    </div>
    <p>Bianco Carrara</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material4'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/imperialred.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='granit' value='Imperial Red'>
    </div>
    <p>Imperial Red</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material5'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile4.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='granit' value='Absolute Black'>
    </div>
    <p>Absolute Black</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material6'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/cloudy.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='kalksten' value='Bianco Talia Sesame2'>
    </div>
    <p>Bianco Talia Sesame2</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material7'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/MugalaWhite.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='marmor' value='Mugala White'>
    </div>
    <p>Mugala White</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div class='material' id='material8'>
  <a class='product'>
    <div class='tiles_bg' style='background:url(media/images/tile3.jpg);'>
      <input class='select_all' type='checkbox' name='Övrigt sortiment' value='Ever Green marmor'>
    </div>
    <p>Ever Green marmor</p>
  </a>
</div>
```